# How i make simplification/abstraction circuit in proteus?

Tags: proteus

[image]I have make 4bit ADDER only using basic logic gates, if i want make another component it will make full of space, so i want make ADDER be simple in proteus like an Integrated Circuit.

Here my own work, which we can see the Input on BOTTOM and the output on TOP, while Bottom Left is my design.

I want make Simple like bottom-left square at that image, but how to connect the pins from digital logic to that square pins?

Comment: As you know as a regular user asking many questions, the site is not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is very easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract.

Comment: I have Edited the question